# OData PageResult<TObject> - Wrong Serialization

Tags: c#, odata, webapi, paginator

I currently have a web API on in version Dotnet 7 and here I would like to use OData as query framework for some GET requests. For this I use the object PageResult<TObj> to display the value Count to the frontend. Now I have the problem that when I return the PageResult<TObj> via Ok(pageResult); that all values are initially displayed without restriction.
https://<baseUrl>/v1/staticreceiver/odatatest1:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "onlyNotification": false,
            "email": "test1@example.com",
            "firstName": "Test1",
            "lastName": "Last1",
            "templates": [
                "template1",
                "template2",
                "template3"
            ],
            "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "createdAt": "2023-03-16T08:08:36.26778+01:00"
        },
...
    ],
    "count": 3
}
```

As you can see the correct properties count and items are available, but if I now make it `https://\<baseUrl\>/v1/staticreceiver/odatatest1?$filter=Email eq 'Dennis'`
or
`https://\<baseUrl\>/v1/staticreceiver/odatatest1?$skip=1&top=2`
we will only see the data inside of items:

```
[
        {
            "onlyNotification": false,
            "email": "test1@example.com",
            "firstName": "Test1",
            "lastName": "Last1",
            "templates": [
                "template1",
                "template2",
                "template3"
            ],
            "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "createdAt": "2023-03-16T08:08:36.26778+01:00"
        },
...
]
```

I will only see the pure data that should normally be shown in the wrap object FileResult under items.

I try before to do it with the following code:

Registration of OData in Program.cs

```
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
            {
                stringEnumConverter,
            },
        };

        services.AddControllers().AddOData(options =>
        {
            options.EnableQueryFeatures(100);
        });
```

Dummy Data to test the api:

```
private IQueryable<StaticMailReceiversEntity> GetStaticMailReceiver()
    {
        return new List<StaticMailReceiversEntity>
        {
            new ()
            {
                Email = "test1@sergo.de",
                FirstName = "Test1",
                LastName = "Last1",
                OnlyNotification = false,
                Templates = new List<string>
                {
                    "template1", "template2", "template3",
                },
            },
            new ()
            {
                Email = "test2@sergo.de",
                FirstName = "Test2",
                LastName = "Last2",
                OnlyNotification = false,
                Templates = new List<string>
                {
                    "template1", "template2", "template3",
                },
            },
            new ()
            {
                Email = "test3@sergo.de",
                FirstName = "Test3",
                LastName = "Last3",
                OnlyNotification = false,
                Templates = new List<string>
                {
                    "template1", "template2", "template3",
                },
            },
        }.AsQueryable();
    }
```

My two methods out of the controller with that i try to test odata with Filter Options Parameter and without.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("odatatest1")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public async Task<ActionResult<StaticMailReceiversEntity>> GetODataOptions1Async(ODataQueryOptions<StaticMailReceiversEntity> options)
    {
        var plainQueryable = GetStaticMailReceiver();

        var queryable = options.ApplyTo(plainQueryable);

        var typedQueryable = queryable.Cast<StaticMailReceiversEntity>();

        var fileResult = new PageResult<StaticMailReceiversEntity>(
            typedQueryable,
            null,
            plainQueryable.Count());

        return Ok(fileResult);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("odatatest2")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public async Task<ActionResult<StaticMailReceiversEntity>> GetODataOptions2Async()
    {
        var queryable = GetStaticMailReceiver();

        var fileResult = new PageResult<StaticMailReceiversEntity>(
            queryable,
            null,
            queryable.Count());

        return Ok(fileResult);
    }
```

How can i get the correct paging object every time with items, nextLink and with count property?
Without the middleware of odata removes the additional data.

Thank you for your help. I hope you have other ideas to solve that problem. :)

Kind Regards
Dennis